# Not able to get the @jack-henry/banno-plugin-framework-bridge module to work

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I am integrating @jack-henry/banno-plugin-framework-bridge module in the plugin server. I have installed it globally and copied the banno-plugin-framework-bridge.js from dist folder to the root folder of the plugin server. I then included it in the response HTML as per following

```
<script type="module">
    import { enableRouter } from "./banno-plugin-framework-bridge.js";
    enableRouter();
</script>
```

Is this procedure right?
Also, I get the following error:
**Cannot GET /banno-plugin-framework-bridge.js.**
What must be going wrong?

Comment: It depends a lot on the specific tech stack that you are using. We have installation steps for _Node.js_, in particular. You'll have to adapt those steps to what works for your platform in terms of adding JavaScript modules. https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/userinterface/banno-plugin-framework-bridge/#installation

Comment: I am using Node.js stack and following the documented steps.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused because the original question mentions "[...]copied the banno-plugin-framework-bridge.js from dist folder to the root folder of the plugin server.".  When installing via a `package.json` dependency (and using `npm install`), I would expect the module to be loaded into `node_modules` and not require manual copying to a separate location.

Comment: Likewise, the location is slightly different in the docs with a `/js` at the beginning of the location rather than a `./` at the beginning i.e. `import { enableRouter } from "/js/banno-plugin-framework-bridge.js";`.

Comment: You are right in the above two comments. But I deviated because when I used this line `import { enableRouter } from "/js/banno-plugin-framework-bridge.js";`, in the response, I got the 404 error. 
`display1:4          GET https://<path>/js/banno-plugin-framework-bridge.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`
This was my original problem. I should have stated this at the outset, in the problem description.  
So I experimented with static file serving through the root folder. And the result is part of the problem description.

Comment: It's unclear if you are running a project on your local machine or if this is deployed on a server. Can you provide some insight?

Comment: It is deployed on a server

Comment: Interesting. To help narrow down the possibilities, what happens if you run the code locally?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but the "Enabling" and "Installation" sections have been updated in https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/userinterface/banno-plugin-framework-bridge/. Hopefully this reduces some confusion on how you can serve up the Plugin Bridge files.